# how to get the values from json object in retrofit android

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

All the thing working fine but how to call the the user{first_name,last_name,email}

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of your code but include the actual code as text in your question. What do you mean by "calling the user{...}"? Can't you just read the value via the getter from your `RetroPhoto` instance?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call a retrofit method in this way,

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
  @POST("employer/login")
  Call<ResponseModelEmplyrLogin> loginEmployer(

        @Field("data") String data);


 public void loginEmployer(String data, final MyApiCallbackEmplyrLogin<EmployrDataBean> callback) {
    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.createService();

    Call<ResponseModelEmplyrLogin> call = apiService.loginEmployer(data);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseModelEmplyrLogin>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseModelEmplyrLogin> call, Response<ResponseModelEmplyrLogin> response) {
          //Write your code
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseModelEmplyrLogin> call, Throwable t) {
           //Write your code
        }
    });
}
```

Check out this link https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/networking/retrofit-android-tutorial/ ...I think this will be helpful